# C++ cross-folder include failing

Tags: c++, include

I've got a project which has two source folders (main and lib). It produces a shared library and an executable. It is currently built as so:

- copy all files from both folders into a new temp folder
- run lib_makefile
- run main_makefile
- copy binaries out
- delete temp folder

This struck me as being a weird way to do things, so I tried building each in-place by adding `-I../main` to lib_makefile (and vice-versa). Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.

Illustrative example:
foo.cpp (in lib) includes bar.h (in main), which includes baz.h (back in lib).

When I try to compile the shared lib, it correctly locates bar.h in main/, but then bails out with "no such file or directory" claiming it cannot find baz.h, even though baz.h is in the same directory as lib_makefile!

All includes are in the format #include "xxx.h" (i.e no relative paths in the include statements).

Is there a way to get this to work? I feel like I must be missing something obvious..

(nb: I can't modify the #includes because other people still build this the copy-everything-across way)

Comment: Have you tried also adding something like `-I../lib` to the library makefile too?

Comment: It does include 'this directory' but when processing a file in `../main` that is 'this directory', not the one you ran make from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add something like `-I../lib` (or whatever your library path is) to the makefile for the library as well.

The reason for this is that the pre-processor looks for include-files relative to the directory the *current* file is in, not from where the *original* file is in.

Comment: Or simply `-I.` since that's the same as `-I../lib` when in the `lib` dir